# Как правильно работать с dev и продакшн?

Tags: git, build

Всем, **привет**!

Уважаемые, **Git-знатоки**, объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно работать с гитом.

**Задача:** разработка на локальной машине сайта и последующая отправка изменений в удаленный репозиторий.

**Что есть сейчас:** локальный проект под версионным контролем (гит-репозиторий, в нем -дцать коммитов), есть сервер (хостинг) с пустым гит-репозиторием.

**Что было сделано (эксперименты):** пробовал делать ветку build (она же продакшн), мержил туда нужные файлы для сайта, пуш-ил в удаленный репозиторий, затем делал пулл из удаленого репозиория - файлы подтягивались. Но так, видимо, до конца и не понял, в чем соль. Ибо когда продолжал работать над проектом (master) и затем вливал в ветку build основную ветку разработки, была куча ошибок мержа и не ничего не получалось в конечном итоге.

**Как вижу разработку:** есть основная ветка (мастер), в ней ведется разработка. Есть продакшн-ветка, она же build. В продакшн-ветке разработка не ведется, а только принимаются необходимые измнения из Мастера. Когда требуется внести изменения на сайт, делается коммит. Затем этот коммит накатывается (???) на ветку build. После чего ветка билд push-ится в пустой удаленный репозиторий. А из него в рабочий сайт (тоже под версионным контролем) делается pull. Как-то так...

Прошу не судить строго, ибо мало опыта, и не лить "воды".
За качественный ответ-разъяснение, заранее благодарен!

Comment: @scorp24, негласно принятая модель - master-ветка является продакшеном, т.е. там лежит последняя стабильная версия, а основная ветвь разработки лежит в dev.  
Конфликты при мерджах - обычное дело, надо просто смотреть что там не так и разруливать.

Comment: Etki, спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

В отличие от 99% задающих здесь вопросы по git, вы всё делаете правильно. Разберитесь, почему у вас ошибки при мерже master'а в build, и жизнь заиграет новыми красками.

Comment: pirj, спасибо, что откликнулись. Пробую делать со --squash, в этом случае при коммите можно принять меры по отношению конфликтным файлам автоматически, в частности опцией Ours или theirs. Но как быть если надо например к одним файлам (они будут неизменны) применить опцию ours, а к другим theirs (т.е. автоматизировать процесс.)????

Comment: Откуда у вас вообще конфликты, кто-то ещё делает коммиты, помимо вас?

Comment: вобщем получилось решить при помощи --squash и атрибутов в конфиге, но возникает следующий вопрос как отфильтровать ненужные файлы для продашена, но в девелопе они были под версионным контролем, например .less-файлы и т.д.???

Comment: @pirj, конфликты **при мердже**.

Comment: эмммм....я весьма у'гугл'ен этими "конфликты при мердже", но тем не менее вопрос открыт...

Comment: Добавляете эти файлы в .gitignore. Либо есть вариант генерировать эти файлы (css, полученный из less) локально, и коммитить, и настроить подакшн так, чтобы он их сам не пытался конфертировать.

Comment: Суть здесь такая, в девелопе есть файлы .less и есть .css (под версионным контролем, все изменения коммитятся), .less естественным образом конвертируется в этот самый min.css. Есть файлы .gitignore  в том же девелопе и тоже под версионным контролем. Далее я создал ветку продакшн (build), в этой ветке никаких изменений не происходит (по изначальной задумке), туда только вливаются изменения из девелопа и потом пушатся в удаленный bare-репозиторий.

Comment: Так вот в этих двух ветках - продакшн и девелоп, есть одинаковые файлы под вресионным контролем разных веток, при мерже из девелопа в продакшн естественно возникает конфликт. Например, в обоих ветках есть файлы гитигнор, и мне надо, чтобы эти файлы в продакшн не менялись при мерже - решил merge=ours'ом в гитатрибутах. Но как быть, например, с .less файлами, которые при мерже тоже попадают в индекс?

Comment: @scorp24, то, что вы описываете, - превращение less в css - на самом деле является задачей вовсе не версионной системы контроля. Это значит, что между VCS и продакшен-сервером должен стоять build-обработчик, который и будет превращать .less в .css, а оригинальные .less удалять (если они не используются на клиенте). Проще всего обзавестись тем или иным CI-сервером или взвесить эту задачу на IDE (тот же PHPStorm должен уметь).

Зачем вам отдельный .gitignore на продакшене - не знаю. По идее продакшен - эта та же dev-ветка (ну хорошо, rc-), просто в нее попадают стабильные версии.